# Replace image with next image and previous image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, carousel

I am in the process of building out a carousel and can't seem to figure out how to replace my current image with the next image and previous one. I've attached a codepen and a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmQjRB

```
JS:
```

```js
      const img_con = document.getElementById('img-con');
    const img_con1 = document.getElementById('img-con-1');
    const img_con2 = document.getElementById('img-con-2');
      const next = document.getElementById('next');
      const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
    
       const images = ['https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506126483163-f4d1558dbf85?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506252374453-ef5237291d83?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525183995014-bd94c0750cd5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg']
    
       let i = images.length;
    
        next.onclick = ()=> {
          i = (i<images.length) ? (i= i+1) : (i=1);
          img_con.innerHTML = "<img class='img' src="+images[i-1]+">";
        }
        
        prev.onclick = ()=> {
          i = (i<images.length+1 && i>1) ?(i= i-1):(i=images.length);
          img_con.innerHTML = "<img class='img' src="+images[i-1]+">";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the images array to have images in appropriate order.

```
const images = ['https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525183995014-bd94c0750cd5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506126483163-f4d1558dbf85?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506252374453-ef5237291d83?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg'
]
```

Also you need to run a for loop to check the index. I am attaching a fully working code for next button click.

```
let i =0;
next.onclick = () => {
        let temp = images[0];
        for (let index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {


            images[index] = images[index + 1];
            if (index === images.length-1 ) {

                images[index] = temp;
            }

        }

        img_con1.innerHTML = "<img class='img' src=" + images[i] + ">";
        img_con.innerHTML = "<img class='img' src=" + images[i + 1] + ">";
        img_con2.innerHTML = "<img class='img' src=" + images[i + 2] + ">";
    }
```

And for the pre button yu need to run loop backwords

```
let j = 0;
    prev.onclick = () => {

        let temp = images[images.length-1];
        for (let index = images.length-1; index >=0; index--) {


            images[index] = images[index - 1];
            if (index === 0 ) {
                console.log(index);
                images[index] = temp;
            }

        }
        img_con1.innerHTML = "<img class='img' src=" + images[j] + ">";
        img_con.innerHTML = "<img class='img' src=" + images[j + 1] + ">";
        img_con2.innerHTML = "<img class='img' src=" + images[j + 2] + ">";
    }
```

Comment: Getting undefined

Comment: where are you getting undefined? have you updated yur codepen? I can have a look there

Comment: Only one mistake.  start with 0, so let i = 0; instaed of  let i = images.length;

Comment: Nice, any thoughts on the previous btn?

Comment: same, just run the loop backwards.

Comment: Hmmm... this doest fire...for (let index = 0; index > images.length; index--) {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182459/discussion-between-narendra-mongiya-and-user992731).